# can polymer-cli@next damaged somehow polymer 1

Tags: polymer

Until I started the new polymer-cli my projects done in Polymer 1 was running as expected. Now, when I tried to start them via gulp serve I get error.

I tried updated by "bower update" and I got

```
bower polymer#1.11.3                                       ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-28649quOp0xfcp3e\polymer-1.11.3'

Stack trace:
C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\fstream\lib\dir-reader.js:96:25
C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:88:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\bin\bower.js:113:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Logger.emit (C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
    at C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\commands\index.js:49:24
    at _rejected (C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:864:24)
    at C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
System info:
Bower version: 1.8.4
Node version: 8.11.1
OS: Windows_NT 6.1.7601 x64
```

Could that be related to the fact I installed "npm install -g polymer-cli@next"? What could I check around?